# Lightmap texture tiling with Three.js

Tags: three.js

I know about [texture tiling](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Textures/Texture). However can a lightmap be tiled the same way?

I can't manage to tile a lightmap texture using the following snippet of code. No repeat or offset is taken into account.

```
var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Map.jpg');
var lightMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Light map.png');
lightMap.wrapS = lightMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
lightMap.repeat.set(.455078, .455078);
lightMap.offset.set(.472343, .546562);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: map, lightMap: lightMap});
jsonLoader.load('Model.json', function (geometry) {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightmaps do not support offset/repeat in three.js, and in fact require a separate set of UVs.

three.js r.69

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was expecting.

Comment: Sorry to be so demanding, however can you provide a source that verifies your answer?

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/lightmap_vertex.glsl and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/lightmap_fragment.glsl

Comment: I have no skill in GLSL. Anyway, your statement seems right from an empirical point of view.